# Why do glibc's `system()` and `posix_spawn()` deal with signals?

Tags: c, linux, signals, glibc, systems-programming

1. The current [POSIX-wide implementation of `system()` in glibc](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/posix/system.c.html) for the parent process:

   1.a sets the process-wide signal handlers for SIGINT and SIGQUIT to *ignore*

   1.b and blocks SIGCHLD.
2. The current [Linux-specific implementation of `posix_spawn()` in glibc](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/spawni.c.html) blocks *all* signals on the parent process.

What are the reasons for these signal handling manipulations?

Comment: I think 1.b is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59212770/420683 but I'm not sure about blocking the signal _only on the thread which calls `system()`_.

Comment: 1.a is [mandated by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html), and the "Application Notes" shed some light on the why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The current POSIX-wide implementation of `system()` in glibc for the parent process:
>
> 1.a sets the process-wide signal handlers for SIGINT and SIGQUIT to ignore
>
> 1.b and blocks SIGCHLD.

`system()` has a rather specific use-case:

- parent is a single-threaded process
- spawn an *interactive* process
- parent is non-interactive while child is running

Think of `:read !<cmd>` in vim, or `shell <cmd>` in gdb.

From [POSIX 2018](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html):

> Ignoring SIGINT and SIGQUIT in the parent process prevents
> coordination problems (two processes reading from the same terminal,
> for example) when the executed command ignores or catches one of the
> signals. It is also usually the correct action when the user has given
> a command to the application to be executed synchronously (as in the
> `'!'` command in many interactive applications). In either case, the
> signal should be delivered only to the child process, not to the
> application itself. There is one situation where ignoring the signals
> might have less than the desired effect. This is when the application
> uses `system()` to perform some task invisible to the user. If the
> user typed the interrupt character (`"^C"`, for example) while
> `system()` is being used in this way, one would expect the application
> to be killed, but only the executed command is killed. Applications
> that use `system()` in this way should carefully check the return
> status from `system()` to see if the executed command was successful,
> and should take appropriate action when the command fails.
>
> Blocking SIGCHLD while waiting for the child to terminate prevents the
> application from catching the signal and obtaining status from
> `system()`'s child process before `system()` can get the status
> itself.

The last paragraph refers to the mechanism for waiting on processes:

- you can have the kernel send a SIGCHLD to the parent when the child exits
- the parent can execute `waitpid()` or similar

It is possible to do both or neither; but the child process will (unless configured) become a zombie process until the parent calls `waitpid()`. I would therefore consider the SIGCHLD as an extra option, e.g. useful for single-threaded processes which don't want to block for child processes (consider shell background tasks).

Since the parent might have a signal handler installed for SIGCHLD, and that signal handler might call `waitpid()` or similar before `system()` internally executes `waitpid()`, the `system()` implementation might lose the information about the child exit. Only the first `waitpid()` receives that information.

Note that we assume the parent process is single-threaded, therefore blocking SIGCHLD on the parent *thread* is sufficient.

You can also set options on any signal handler you install for SIGCHLD that influence this mess, which is something I have not looked into.

---

> 2. The current Linux-specific implementation of posix_spawn() in glibc blocks all signals on the parent process.

This is because `posix_spawn()` uses something like `vfork()`. From glibc's `spawni.c`:

```c
/* The Linux implementation of posix_spawn{p} uses the clone syscall directly
   with CLONE_VM and CLONE_VFORK flags and an allocated stack.  The new stack
   and start function solves most the vfork limitation (possible parent
   clobber due stack spilling). The remaining issue are:
   
   1. That no signal handlers must run in child context, to avoid corrupting
      parent's state.
   2. The parent must ensure child's stack freeing.
   3. Child must synchronize with parent to enforce 2. and to possible
      return execv issues.
      
   The first issue is solved by blocking all signals in child, even
   the NPTL-internal ones (SIGCANCEL and SIGSETXID).  The second and
   third issue is done by a stack allocation in parent, and by using a
   field in struct spawn_args where the child can write an error
   code. CLONE_VFORK ensures that the parent does not run until the
   child has either exec'ed successfully or exited.  */
```

`CLONE_VFORK` is meant to provide one aspect of the venerable `vfork()` function.
`vfork` creates a child process but both the parent and the child process *share the same memory*:

Spawning a new process on Unix systems was originally based on the model of `fork()`+`exec()`:
First, the parent process calls `fork()` which literally creates a "fork" in the execution
by spawning off a child process which runs on a copy of the memory of the parent process
and starts execution by returning from `fork()`.
Both threads, the spawner in the parent and the new child thread return from `fork()`
but operate on different copies of the same memory contents.
The child process would then do some minor things like setting up the stdin/stdout/stderr file descriptors
and finally call `exec()`.
That `exec()` syscall replaces the child's memory with an image of the executable to be executed.

Since `fork()` needs to provide a memory copy, it was originally slow and expensive
(there were no copy-on-write hardware features).
Therefore, `vfork()` was provided: here, the parent and child process *operate on the same memory*.
That is, modifications to memory done by the child affect the parent and vice versa.
Because it's dangerous for two threads to operate on the same stack,
`vfork()` blocks the spawner thread (in the parent process) until the child has either executed `exec()` or `exit()`.
The `exec()` syscall stops memory sharing, in other words,
the child process will have its own memory after `exec()`.

In Linux, there's neither a `fork()` nor a `vfork()` system call.
Instead, both features are provided via flags to the `clone()` system call:
`CLONE_VFORK` and `CLONE_VM`.
`CLONE_VFORK` implements the blocking aspect of `vfork()`, that is,
it blocks the spawner thread until the child calls `exec()` or `exit()`.
`CLONE_VM` controls the sharing of memory:
if set, both processes operate on the same memory (until `exec()`);
if unset, the child will have a (copy-on-write) clone of the memory of the parent.

glibc according to the comment is mostly concerned about the child clobbering the stack of the parent.
To avoid this, it allocates a new stack for the child and uses `clone()` with `CLONE_VM | CLONE_VFORK`.
The `clone()` syscall provides an additional parameter where you can set the stack of the child.
For `vfork()` proper, that would be the stack of the parent;
glibc here places its dedicated allocation.

Any signal handler executed in the child also operate on the memory of the parent,
but the state of the child process is a bit strange:

- The threads of the parent process are not part of the same thread group (process), yet they access the same data and locks.
- The thread ID and process ID of the parent do not fit to the thread-local storage of the child (glibc shares the TLS between parent and child by not setting `CLONE_SETTLS`).
- The child shares the memory with the parent, but other resources like file descriptors are not shared. File descriptors specifically are only inherited - meaning that closing a file descriptor only affects the child, for example.
- If the parent (thread) receives a signal while waiting for the child in `clone(CLONE_VFORK)`, it will only process that signal after the child `exit()`s or `exec()`s. (This is documented in the man page for `vfork()` but not in the one for `clone()`.)

Signals can either be sent to the child directly (for whatever reason), occur within the child (e.g. SIGSEGV or SIGTTIN) or affect an entire process group (e.g. SIGINT). Some of these aren't entirely under the control of the code between `clone()` and `exec()` (like SIGINT and SIGTTIN), which explains why the signals should not be handled in the child using the existing signal handlers of the parent.
`posix_spawn()` therefore restores all signal handlers to their default disposition in the child.

This still doesn't quite explains why signals are blocked *in the parent*, though.
I assume glibc wants to avoid a race condition where a signal can arrive in the child in between the `clone()` and the set-up of the signal handlers in the child.
Glibc does restore the signal mask after resetting the signal handlers in the child (and after performing the `posix_spawn()` file actions).
Recently, the kernel added another flag `CLONE_CLEAR_SIGHAND` for `clone()`, which at least takes care of setting the signal disposition / uninstalling any custom signal handlers. I wonder if this means you could also get rid of the signal blocking (in the parent).

Since we have allocated a stack for the child, we also need to free it.
And it has been allocated in the memory space of the parent;
the child cannot free it (easily) because it runs on that stack up until `exec()` which might even return on failure.
So the parent needs to wait until the child is done (`exec()` successful or `exit()` called)
before releasing the stack allocation.
I'm not sure why `waitpid()` was not used as the synchronization mechanism,
the comment in glibc merely states that this synchronization is the reason for using `CLONE_VFORK`.

Comment: Note that there are strange interactions between signals and other concepts like TTYs. E.g. if `tostop` is set on the TTY, parent+child are in the background, and the child accesses the TTY, then both the parent and the child will receive a SIGSTOP. The SIGSTOP however will be delayed by `CLONE_VFORK` on the parent, meaning the parent will _stop again_ after exiting from `clone()`. Not sure what happens when you send a SIGCONT while the parent is still within `clone()`.